# Category List With Comma & Link

Tags: categories

Trying to list the categories for post separated by a comma with link to the category archive.

```
                <?php
                foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
                if($category->name==$homecat) continue;
                $category_id = get_cat_ID( $category->cat_name );
                $category_link = get_category_link( $category_id );
                echo '<span class="cat"><a href="'.$category_link.'">'.$category->cat_name.'</a></span>';
                } ?>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the_category if you are in the loop:

`<?php the_category(', '); ?>`

If not, then use this code:

```
<?php
$output = '';
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
    if($category->name==$homecat) continue;
    $category_id = get_cat_ID( $category->cat_name );
    $category_link = get_category_link( $category_id );

    if(!empty($output))
        $output .= ', ';
    $output .= '<span class="cat"><a href="'.$category_link.'">'.$category->cat_name.'</a></span>';
}
echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Ali, I just used your great little piece of code myself for a project. Elegant solution to the "add comma or not"? problem, much better than what I usually use :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the loop you can use `the_category`
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_category